# Trouble moving python requests to node.js requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I currently have the functioning code in python

```
import requests
import json
address = "*address here*"
viewkey = "*viewkey here*"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = "https://api.mymonero.com:8443/get_address_txs"

data = {"address":address,"view_key":viewkey}
data = json.dumps(data)


response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

And I tried to move to nodejs to integrate it with another program I have written

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://api.mymonero.com:8443/get_address_txs',
  headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
  data: JSON.stringify({
      address:"address",
      viewkey:"viewkey"
  })
};

request.post(options,function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
})
```

I assumed the code would be identical but clearly not I get an error from the server with the second segment of code. Please could someone help me migrate this?

Note: I know requests in python has a json attribute I have written it in python this way for clarity.

For the record the response I get from the javascript is:

```
{
  "Error": "Problems parsing JSON"
}
```

When I get from python:

```
{
  "total_received": "152840132538",
  "scanned_height": 2589644,
  "scanned_block_height": 1320308,
  "start_height": 2586111,
  ...
}
```

Comment: just curious, why do you want to convert python to nodejs ?

Comment: Because there's a bunch of cool libraries in node that don't exist in python and don't want to spend forever porting them.

Comment: hmmm cool libraries in node, examples ?

Comment: the steam library in node is comprehensive yet the equivalent in python is non-existant, the only one that exists is the one I've written myself, you can look [here](https://github.com/Plasma2450/python-steamcommunity)

Comment: fair enough ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right I'm an accidental genius I have no idea why my current method wasn't working but the solution I came up with was:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://api.mymonero.com:8443/get_address_txs',
  headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
  json: {
      "address":"*address*",
      "view_key":"*viewkey*"
  }
};

request.post(options,function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
})
```

No idea why it works but hey that's life thank you so much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Do not stringify your msg. That should be it.

Comment: Tried it but to no avail :/ get the same response

Answer (score 2):

In your json, in python the key is `view_key`, in javascript it's `view key`.

Also, the request library doesn't have a `data` key in it's options. You can use `body` to set the raw body. If you use `json`, the body will be the son representation of the dict you pass, and the `Content-Type` header is set for you .

Comment: Yes sorry you're correct I've changed my javascript but it still didn't work got the same reply.

Comment: yeah, edited my answer: there is no `data` in option object for request library